# Mark a method for static use

Tags: c#, methods, static

How can I mark a method to use only if the class object was initialized as static?

For example:

```
public class A
{

    public A()
    {

    }

    public void DoIt()
    {

    {

    public void DoItStatic()
    {

    }
}

public class B
{

    private A _aa = new A();
    private static A _aaStatic = new A();


    public B()
    {

    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        _aa.DoItStatic(); //Generate Error for that.
        _aaStatic.DoItStatic(); //it's fine
    {   

}
```

So, if someone tries to use _aa.DoItStatic(), where _aa is not initialized as static, we generate an error.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't achieve that.

Comment: So, there are no any options to make a check or anything else in class A?

Comment: How do you define "if the class object was initialized as static"? Consider this instance method code: `var aClass = new A(); staticClass.aClass = aClass;` - it was initialized in an instance method, but is being assigned to a static field. What is your motivation for doing this?

Comment: This is feeling like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem .  **Why** do you want to do this?

Comment: How do you define "if the class object was initialized as static"? I mean if it was initialized like - private static A _aaStatic = new A();
And it needs for example to keep **loca**l PowerShell session.

Comment: Consider [this code](https://pastebin.com/ecraX7Rw). The variable is _intialized_ from instance code, not static code. Do you mean that you want to know if the variable holding the instance is static? Also, what does PowerShell have to do with anything?

Comment: This is necessary as a temporary solution.
Now, as in the example above, "doit" always creates a separate local session when called, if the class is not static - this is good, because the PowerShell command if not called as "Start-Job" locks the console until it finishes.
I want to do a method for "Start-Job", which should be executed if the object was initialized as static.

Comment: Would a singleton class be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so. But I will look in this direction in more detail, perhaps this will prove to be a useful direction.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you make  it static like   public static void DoItStatic() instead?

Comment: No I can't, methods can't be static in this class.

Comment: Could you change the constructor to accept a flag to say if it's static or not? Of course, this depends on consumers setting it correctly.

Comment: Hmm, the idea with the flag is good. If there is no better idea, I will use it.
Thank you.